# ffmpeg: padding is not always transparent

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using a simple ffmpeg command to resize and pad images to fit within a 960x540 frame. I'd like the padding to be transparent but I get different behavior on different images.

Command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i image.PNG -vf \
"scale=iw*min(960/iw\,540/ih):ih*min(960/iw\,540/ih),pad=960:540:(960-iw)/2:(540-ih)/2:color=#00000000" \
new.png
```

It seems that PNG screenshots I have taken get a transparent background as expected. JPGs seem to get the black padding, even if I convert them to PNG before hand.

**The difference I seem to see is rgb24 vs rgba. Is that the issue? If so, how can I change that property before doing the padding?**

Black padding:

```
Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24, 960x540 [SAR 1926:1925 DAR 3424:1925], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
```

Transparent padding:

```
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba, 960x540, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the [format filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) to your filterchain before using pad:

```
-vf scale,format=rgba,pad
```

Comment: Perfect - no pre-conversion required. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one answer: If I first convert the JPG to a PNG **and change the pixel format to rgba at the same time**, then I can do the padding, and it will be transparent. It doesn't seem to work if I try and do it at the same time as I do the padding though.

Here's the command for the conversion:

```
ffmpeg -i image.jpg -pix_fmt rgba image.png
```